# Inconsistent behaviour with udev and "su -c "

Tags: udev, alsa, su, jack

I have a JACK server set up in my computer to take care of all the sound inputs and outputs. When I connect an external USB sound card (name: CODEC), I want it to be detected by udev, so I setup udev rules to detect when the card is plugged in and out and to run a command accordingly:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", ATTR{id}=="CODEC", RUN+="/home/myname/scripts/soundcard.sh connected"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="sound", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="USB_Audio_CODEC", RUN+="/home/myname/scripts/soundcard.sh disconnected"
```

To check whether the card is being detected, the soundcard.sh script runs

```
$ aplay -l > logfile1.txt
```

I find in the output:

```
card 2: CODEC [USB Audio CODEC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
```

as I should, but when I use

```
$ su -c "aplay -l > logfile2.txt" -l myname
```

I don't! Running the script as user yields different results! What's going on? Any clues?